# ask with echo:false does not work in Capistrano 3.2.1

Tags: php, ruby, wordpress, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano 3.2.1 to deploy a wordpress project with bedrock. I'm asking for a passwort in the deploy.rb config file.

I want to hide the password input, the Capistrano docs says this works like this:

```
# Capistrano > 3.2.0 supports echo: false
ask(:password, nil, echo: false)
```

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-get-capistrano-to-prompt-for-a-password/

But it does not. I'm getting the error:

```
cap aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/env.rb:30:in `ask' config/deploy.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => staging
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you try upgrading to a more recent Cap 3.x?

Comment: Updated to version 3.4.0 and it works! Thank you!